# Robolectric tests running in Android Studio but not on the command line

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, robolectric

I'm trying to run unit tests using Robolectric; they run fine under Android Studio, but the exact same tests fail when running in the command line - which is a big deal, I need to be able to run them from my continuous integration platform, not just from an IDE.

I suspect that I'm missing some command-line argument (say, a classpath or something similar) or calling the wrong task - otherwise the test wouldn't run at all from Android Studio. Some relevant details; the test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", resourceDir = "res", emulateSdk = 19)
public class SplashActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void testActivity() {
        SplashActivity splashActivity = new SplashActivity();
        String appName = splashActivity.getString(R.string.app_name); // HERE, line 20
        assertEquals(appName, "App");
    }

}
```

As mentioned above, it runs fine in Android Studio (by right-clicking the test file and selecting `Run 'SplashActivityTest'`) but when running it from the command line it fails in the line marked with `HERE`, with the following stack trace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: unknown resource 2131492893
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.getAndResolve(ShadowAssetManager.java:309)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.getResourceText(ShadowAssetManager.java:69)
  at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText(AssetManager.java)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:240)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.getText(ShadowResources.java:361)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:330)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowContext.getString(ShadowContext.java:39)
  at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowContextWrapper.getString(ShadowContextWrapper.java:69)
  at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java)
  at path.to.myApp.activities.SplashActivityTest.testActivity(SplashActivityTest.java:20)
  // ... and so on ...
```

I'm using this to run from the command line (notice that in here and in Android Studio I'm using the Gradle wrapper):

```
project-root$ ./gradlew test --continue
```

Also: I'm using Android Studio `1.1.0`, Gradle version is `2.3`, Robolectric's version is `3.0-SNAPSHOT` and Robolectric's Gradle plugin version is `1.0.1`

Comment: Oscar, can you run it with `--debug` option. I expect that you will see message about issue to find manifest file and using the default one

Comment: @EugenMartynov You're on the right track, I get this on the console: `WARNING: No manifest file found at ./app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. Falling back to the Android OS resources only.` can you elaborate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that this is a known issue. The resources of a project are looked for in the wrong directory when running tests from the command line, here's a [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158015) to the issue; for now the workaround is to write a custom test runner as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com/example/myapplication/CustomRobolectricRunner.java):

```
public class RobolectricGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public RobolectricGradleTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
        String buildVariant = (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.isEmpty() ? "" : BuildConfig.FLAVOR+ "/") + BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;
        String intermediatesPath = BuildConfig.class.getResource("").toString().replace("file:", "");
        intermediatesPath = intermediatesPath.substring(0, intermediatesPath.indexOf("/classes"));

        System.setProperty("android.package", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        System.setProperty("android.manifest", intermediatesPath + "/manifests/full/" + buildVariant + "/AndroidManifest.xml");
        System.setProperty("android.resources", intermediatesPath + "/res/" + buildVariant);
        System.setProperty("android.assets", intermediatesPath + "/assets/" + buildVariant);
    }

}
```

The test cases must be updated accordingly to use the custom test runner *instead of* the `@Config` annotation:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class SplashActivityTest {
    // tests same as before
}
```

Also, it's recommended to perform a `clean` when running the tests from the command line, given that the workaround depends on the contents of the build directory, we don't want to have stale data there:

```
project-root$ ./gradlew clean test --continue
```

Comment: Just as an addendum to this answer. As of 3/24/2015, I'd recommend using the most recent library **Robolectric 3.0-SNAPSHOT**. This snapshot has a built in **RobolectricGradleTestRunner** that will also work with the BuildVariant elements (Flavor, Type, etc).  With this, one does not need to write a test runner yourself. For the updated runner [a constant config class can be defined like this](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blame/master/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/RobolectricGradleTestRunnerTest.java#L67).

Comment: @abest it still has issues with running tests on a mac

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the same error, but in different way.
I used custom class shadows in tests, So I have to create my own TestRunner class, like this:

```
public class MyRobolectricTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public MyRobolectricTestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    public InstrumentationConfiguration createClassLoaderConfig() {
        InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder builder = InstrumentationConfiguration.newBuilder();
        builder.addInstrumentedClass(AppUtils.class.getName());
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

But above code worked only when I run the unit-test from Andorid studio. Please, check out **code that works for me in both ways: in Studio and from the command-line**:

```
public class MyRobolectricTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public MyRobolectricTestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    public InstrumentationConfiguration createClassLoaderConfig() {
        InstrumentationConfiguration.Builder builder = InstrumentationConfiguration.newBuilder();
        builder.addInstrumentedPackage(com.example.stackoverflow.AppUtils.class.getPackage().getName());
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

Please, note I have the dependency:

```
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
```